# How to scrape JSON from puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, scrape, puppeteer

I login to a site and it gives a browser cookie.

I go to a URL and it is a json response.

How do I scrape the page after entering `await page.goto('blahblahblah.json');`
?

Answer (score 33):

Another way which doesn't give you `intermittent issues` is to evaluate the body when it becomes available and return it as JSON e.g.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: false  //change to true in prod!
    }); 

    const page = await browser.newPage(); 

    await page.goto('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/master/package.json');

   //I would leave this here as a fail safe
    await page.content(); 

    const innerText = await page.evaluate(() =>  {
        return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText); 
    }); 

    console.log("innerText now contains the JSON");
    console.log(innerText);

    //I will leave this as an excercise for you to
    //  write out to FS...

    await browser.close(); 

};

run();
```

Comment: What do you use the variable 'content' for?

Comment: nothing in particular by looks :)  must be left over from testing code

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept the network response, like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  page.on('response', async response => {
    console.log('got response', response._url)
    const data = await response.buffer()
    fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/response.json', data)
  })
  await page.goto('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/master/package.json', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
  await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: I am getting
 `
(node:6503) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Network.getResponseBody): Target closed.
`

Comment: Hmm, I get that occasionally, too. Adding `{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}` seems to help - apparently it was possible to reach `browser.close()` before the whole response body had been loaded.

Comment: Note that you can use `await response.json()` if you want to use the data inside your code.